# Html Tags Getting Posted in Database in Android

Tags: android, html, database, sqlite

Html tags such as  and  tags are getting posted in database.

Here is the image:
 [imageBin](https://imagebin.ca/v/3pqaBmgNg5j2)

And here is the code:

```
private void onFabClick() {
    if (familyHistoryMap.anySubSelected()) {
        for (Node node : familyHistoryMap.getOptionsList()) {
            if (node.isSelected()) {
                String familyString = node.generateLanguage();
                String toInsert = node.getText() + " : " + familyString;
                toInsert = toInsert.replaceAll(Node.bullet,"");
                toInsert = toInsert.replaceAll(" - ",", ");
                toInsert = toInsert.replaceAll("<br/>","");
                if(StringUtils.right(toInsert,2).equals(", ")){
                 toInsert = toInsert.substring(0,toInsert.length()-2);
                }
                toInsert = toInsert+ ".<br/>";

                insertionList.add(toInsert);

            }
        }
    }
```

The code `toInsert = toInsert + <"./br">` is posting the value along with `<br>` tag  how to get rid of these?

Comment: why don't you use the replaceAll call after the last append and use it in the list?

Comment: first you add `".<br/>"` to your data, and then wonder why it is inserted to a DB. Because you wanted it to be inserted. Don't add it if you don't want it.

Comment: ok the reason behind concating  a ".<br/>"  tag  is just to make sure the values on the textView are getting displayed one after the other on each new line. if i dont add it to data it just displays the value in one single line . @VladMatvienko

Comment: yep @Rino i tried that so <./br> didn 't got posted in database but now the values in textview are getting posted in one single line.

Comment: @aniket : post code you are using to set the textview and the code you are sending to database.

Comment: this is quite weird that you want that tag in one place, and don't want it in another place. Probably you need to build the text for textviews separately from text for the database, and add that html tag only when you build the text for textviews?

Comment: The idea you should follow is to use the formatted one to set textview and the non formatted one for the database.